# Check if mean and mode of an array are equal

Tags: ruby, mean, mode

I am trying to return `1` if the mean and mode of an array of numbers are equal, or return `0` otherwise. My code is

```
def MeanMode(arr)
  arrunq = arr.uniq
  if arrunq.length == arr.length
    return 0
  end
  lendiff = arr.length - arrunq.length
  mode = 0
  arr.each do |x|
    if arr.scan(x).length - 1 == lendiff 
      mode += x
    end
  end
  mean = (arr.inject(:+))/(arr.length)
  if mode == mean
    return 1
  end
end
puts MeanMode([1, 2, 3, 3])
```

While testing, I got this error.

```
private method `scan' called for [1, 2, 3, 3]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

I have no idea how to solve it further. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that on line 9 you are trying to call scan on an Array.

Arrays do not have a scan method. Off the top of my head the only thing I can think of with a scan method is String and that takes a regex argument.

Are you trying to count the matches of x in the array?

If so you'll need to Array.count(obj)

```
if arr.count(x) -1 == lendiff
```

Also you need to return a 0 at the end or you'll get nil instead when mode!=mean

```
if mode == mean
  1
else
  0
end
```

(assuming the rest of your code works - I haven't evaluated the logic - just the syntax)

Comment: Running your code makes me think your means of determining the mode isn't correct - but that's a different problem

Answer (score 0):

I got the error, "NoMethodError: undefined method 'scan' for [1, 2, 3, 3]:Array", which is what I expected, as the class `Array` has no method `scan`.  Perhaps you were confusing that with [String#scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-scan).  I don't know how you got the "private method" message.

The lines

```
arrunq = arr.uniq
if arrunq.length == arr.length
  return 0
end
```

will be a problem if, for example,

```
arr = [2]
```

or

```
arr = [2,2,2]
```

Here the mean and mode are both `2`, so your method should return `1`.

Let's start by calculating the mean, using your example for `arr`:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 3]

numerator = arr.reduce(:+) #=> 9
denominator = arr.size     #=> 4
```

If the values of `arr` are all integers (as in your example), the mode will be an integer.  Therefore, if the mean is not an integer, the mean cannot equal the mode, so your method should return `0` (why not `false`?). The mean is an integer if and only if:

```
numerator % denominator == 0
```

so we can add the statement;

```
return 0 unless numerator % denominator == 0
```

In the example I'm using, the left side of the equality is:

```
9 % 4 = 1
```

so we could return `0` without even calculating the mode.

Suppose instead:

```
arr = [1,3,4,4]
```

We compute:

```
numerator = arr.reduce(:+) #=> 12
denominator = arr.size     #=> 4
numerator % denominator    #=> 12 % 4 => 0
```

so in this case we need to compute the mean and mode and see if they are equal:

```
mean = numerator/denominator
      #=> 2 
mode, count = arr.uniq.map { |n| [n, arr.count(n)] }.max_by(&:last)
      #=> [3,2]
mode  #=> 3
count #=> 2
```

`mean != mode`, so again we return `0`.

There are many ways to compute the mode.  The method I've chosen is to perform the following three steps:

```
u = arr.uniq
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
a = u.map { |n| [n, arr.count(n)] }
  #=> [[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]]
a.max_by(&:last) 
  #=> [3, 2]
```

Consider one more case:

```
arr = [1,2,3,3,4,4,11]

numerator = arr.reduce(:+) #=> 28
denominator = arr.size     #=> 7
numerator % denominator    #=> 28 % 7 => 0
mean = numerator/denominator
  #=> 4

mode, count = arr.uniq.map { |n| [n, arr.count(n)] }.max_by(&:last)
  #=> [3, 2]
mode
  #=> 3
count
  #=> 2
```

Here we have a problem concerning the definition of the mode when there is a tie. One option is the following:

```
a = arr.uniq.map { |n| [n, arr.count(n)] }
  #=> [[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 2], [11, 1]]
mx = a.max_by(&:last).last
  #=> 2
mode = a.select { |_, count| count == mx }.map(&:first)
  #=> [3, 4]

mode.include?(mean) #=> [3, 4].include?(4) => true
```

so if we interpreted mode this way, we'd return `1`.

Comment: I think the mathematical definition of mode would state that there are two modes for [1,2,3,3,4,4,11]. Thus the mean cannot be equal to the mode - since the mean cannot be two things simultaneously. However, if the spirit of the question is "is the mean one of the modes", then yes, your final answer of 1 is better.

Comment: @ShadowRadiance, you have a good point, which is why I prefaced that with "One option is...". I thought it would be tedious to say more than that.

Comment: Well I'm nothing if not tedious ;-)

Comment: Here the mean and mode are both 1, so your method should return 1.

Comment: Thanks, tt. I originally had all `1`'s in that example, then, because `1` was being returned, I changed all the values to `2`'s, thinking that would be clearer, but I forgot to change "...mean and mode are both 1"to "... both 2". I fixed that. @ShadowRadiance: you got me.